# Set up multiple cameras on a frame to shoot different angles of an item simultaneously on a budget

Tags: equipment-recommendation, camera

I have an eBay store and I am looking to increase productivity of the photo taking process. Using my phone, taking an image, then rotating the item and taking another image over and over again is a very time consuming and results in inconsistent quality.

I want to set up maybe 6 cameras that are mounted on some frame and have all cameras at different angles pointed at a set. I want to place the item in the center of the set, press one button, and have the 6 cameras take the photo at once. Boom, done.

I would like to do this on a budget of less than $500 for the cameras themselves. Is this possible? I need the quality to be decent for eBay listings, but nothing over the top.

Comment: Are you using a lazy susan/turntable as the stage?  If not, try that before dropping cash on lots of cameras.

Comment: "Multiple cameras" would rather be the solution to "I want to shoot bullet time effects a la Matrix" (so that would actually be "cameras, lots of cameras")

Comment: What kind of objects are you taking pictures of? The process would be _very_ different for shooting role-playing dice than for shooting cars. A turntable or lazy Susan will work well for smaller objects, but obviously not for large objects.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I do like the idea of using a turntable. This will be for motorcycle parts. So, something as small as a gear that is 2 inches in diameter, or as large as a motorcycle frame.

Comment: Something you might have already considered is to use some mirrors to give you line of sight to shoot the other side of your subject.  BTW, you haven't said which kind of $ you're using in your question - you should edit to say it's USD, or AUD, or whatever.

Comment: I'm wondering how you would keep the cameras out of the view of the other cameras...

Answer (score 16):

This is not a good idea. Now you will have inconsistent quality x6. Inconsistent lighting, inconsistent backgrounds, inconsistent framing.

Now for the price, you want to buy 6 super cheap cameras, lights, and a background.

Nope.

---

The first thing is what do you consider inconsistent quality? If you are using auto mode on your phone... change that to manual. It will be free.

Get one decent tripod and cell holder. $20.

One decent background, probably Formica or some laminated material (Avoid glossy. It needs a more advanced setup). $20

Probably a rotating turntable with remote control. $50

Some lights with 2 softboxes, a boom for an overhead light, and a fill light. $100 or some more robust led lights for $200-$300

---

You need to focus on what specific things you have wrong on your images and correct specific things, instead of "inventing" a solution that will most likely cause more problems.

---

I did some basic searches on the prices I wrote. Of course, you can explore more in-depth what specific price-quality-function you need.

---

P.D. With your setup what you want to economize is time, not quality. Framing for multiple cameras, instead of 1 will also be more time-consuming than the rotating turntable.

But you need to invest some time in learning some basics of product photography. You do not need much to learn. In a couple of hours, if you are consistent you will learn something that will be useful for a lifetime.

---

A late addition regarding your comments:

You can find some cheap "action cameras" for the price you want. Besides the fact that the quality will be significantly inferior to a decent camera, they normally come with one fixed super wide-angle lens, so for framing, you need to physically move the camera, and the perspective will not be flattering for the product or you will need to strongly crop the already poor quality image.

The final point that kills the idea of having multiple cameras is the wide range of sizes of the products that you need to photograph. Focus on having one solid setup and you can adapt it for most products.

---

And for heavy objects, like the bike framing you could build a heavy-duty manual lazy Suzan, and use the remote controled for smaller objects.

---

Also, because of the size of the bigger objects, it is a good idea to invest on more robust light stands. A bigger object needs the lights to be further away, so they need more power and normally they need to be bigger.

Comment: just to clarify, the $500 budget was for just the cameras. But thank you for the input!

Comment: Any good point and shoot camera will do, ideally one with manual mode so you can fix exposure during the turntable process but yeah.